# How to use the geo index in mongodb only with integers? (like a board for a game with tiles)

Tags: performance, mongodb

How to use the geo index in mongodb only with integers? (like a board for a game with tiles)

```
use geoTest
db.tiles.remove()
db.tiles.dropIndexes()
db.tiles.ensureIndex({"tiles": "2d"}, {min:-1000000000000000000, max: 1000000000000000000})
db.tiles.insert({id: "1234", tiles: [[10, 10], [20, 20]]})
db.tiles.insert({id: "1234", tiles: [1000000, 1000000]})
db.tiles.find({tiles: {$within:{$box:[[11,11],[20,20]]}}})
db.tiles.find({tiles: {$within:{$box:[[11,11],[10000000,1000000]]}}})
```

but this saves the tiles like this: 10.0 instead of 10.

- Is this going to have performance issues or I should not care about this?
- Having such a big interval in the index is bad? {min:-1000000000000000000, max: 1000000000000000000}
- Using somewhere `tiles: [[10, 10], [20, 20]]` and in other places `tiles: [1000000, 1000000]` can lead to performance issues, or it's ok? (Notice that the first has 2 positions and the second has one position)